# Dired shell command with parameters

Tags: dired, shell-command

I want to provide additional command line options to a command in dired marked with '!',
eg how do I add '-V' to something like 'less'?

Comment: You just type the command (including options) at the prompt.

Comment: What @NickD said. `C-h k !` in Dired.

Comment: So, if I mark 'less' with a '!', then I have to type in 'less -V' at the prompt and not just '-V' ?!!! Doesn't sound right.  I could mark 'less' with a '!' and type in 'gzip -V' at the prompt. I'm obviously missing something....

Comment: Bring up a dired buffer, navigate to some text file using the arrow key and press `!`. That brings up a prompt that says: "! on <filename>: " where `<filename>` is whatever filename your cursor was on when you pressed `!`. Then you type in whatever command you want to run on that file, e.g. "less -S". The point is that you don't have to type the filename: you just type the command (including options).

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to the run the file I selected with parameters, not to run a file on the selected file. Looks like I didn't phrase my question adequately, or misunderstood the way that dired-do-shell-command works. Maybe I can use 'w' with dired, which copies the filename into the mini-buffer, but is there any way to invoke a shell with that file name in it? I guess I'm looking for shortcut for is 'w' 'shell-command' 'c-y' " " parms....  Maybe there is such an option, but I haven't located it yet.

Comment: If that's the point, then don't use dired. You can run any command you want at any time you want with `C-M-!`. But you mentioned `less` which takes a file argument (usually - you can also use it without an argument to operate on stdin, but it is entirely unclear). You should probably delete this question and maybe ask another with what you *really* want to do.

Comment: I thought I had been clear, but will try to be even clearer. I want to be able to execute a program from dired, but instead of simply running it immediately, to show the filename in the minibuffer and allow options to be appended, before pressing enter. It doesn't sound like I'm asking for something very difficult, in fact such an option may actually exist,  but have overlooked it so far.

Comment: The key combo is `M-!`, not `C-M-!` as I mistakenly mentioned above. Try it and see if it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks @NickD. That gives me more or less what I want. I just need to mark the required file in dired with 'w', then 'M-!' followed by 'c-y' and any parameters I choose and I have what I was looking for. If only I could bind that to a key, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dired, you can use `dired-file-name-at-point` to get the name of the executable at point as a string. Then you can prompt for additionnal arguments and build the command. Here is an example.

```lisp
(require 'dired)

(defun execute-file-at-point ()
  "Execute the file at point.

The user may provide additionnal arguments."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((exec-file (dired-file-name-at-point))
         (command-base (concat "./" (file-name-nondirectory exec-file) " "))
         (command (read-string "Additionnal arguments : " command-base)))
    (shell-command command)))
```

You can bind it to a key in dired-mode using :

```lisp
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "e") 'execute-file-at-point)
```

Comment: This is what I get in the minibuffer...
Wrong type argument: commandp, execute-file-at-point

Comment: @balanga Did you evaluate the `defun` to make sure `execute-file-name-at-point` is defined ?

Comment: I copied and pasted the above block, asis, into my  early-init.el. I'll try again with a blank file and just copy that block to see what happens.

Comment: Pressing C-h k show that the command execute-file-at-point should be run, but I get an error - Symbol’s function definition is void: execute-file-at-point

Comment: It looks like you did not evaluate the `defun`. Pasting code in a file does not execute it. Place the code in the `*scratch*` buffer, then run `M-x eval-buffer`. This way everything should be properly defined. Notice that I added `(require 'dired)`.